# Legal free/paid anime streaming sites similar to Netflix/Viaplay?

Tags: streaming-sites

I've used a popular streaming site for many years and now the Japanese government put a stop to it by taking down the site and pulling all content due to copyright claims.

Are there any legal free/paid anime streaming sites that would work in a similar way to Netflix/Viaplay?

Comment: Take note that most of legal streaming sites are geo-blocked due to licensing and rights, so it will depend on where you live.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Well, I'm from Finland so I guess I would need some VPN or other way to bypass geo-blocking.

Answer (score 4):

If you're from SE Asia, try **Muse Asia**. They upload anime on Youtube and some have subtitles in other languages. It's free and legal.

Here's a direct link to their channel's [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGbshtvS9t-8CW11W7TooQg/playlists).

Also, check out this meta post for a list of legal sites to stream/watch anime: [How can I tell if a site is Legal?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal)

Update:

I just found out about another Youtube channel. Its called **Ani-One**. It's also free and legal. Check their playlist [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0wNSTMWIL3qaorLx0jie6A/playlists).

Answer (score 2):

I really like [HIDIVE](https://www.hidive.com/). It's an independent anime streaming company founded in 2017 that is partnered with Sentai Filmworks to distribute shows and movies licensed from Sentai.

Answer (score 1):

[Crunchyroll](https://www.crunchyroll.com) has a big selection and is available in 180+ countries, but quite a few anime can't be watched if you're outside of the US. I recommend installing the [CR-Unblocker add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/crunchy-unblocker/) to bypass this issue, if you're using Firefox. Otherwise you'd have to use a VPN.
It's free with ads. Has a subscription model that removes ads and allows you to watch episodes that aired for less than a week.

Since you're from Finland, a good alternative is [Wakanim](https://www.wakanim.tv/). I haven't used it myself but it's worth looking into.